# Passing one shell script variable to another shell script

Tags: linux, shell, sh, external

I am trying to access one script variable from another script for example,

*script1.sh:*

```
export a=10
export b=20
echo "testing"
exit
```

*script2.sh:*

```
. script1.sh
echo $a
```

The problem involved here is its able to access the variable 'a' from the *script1* in *script2* but its executing **all the commands** written in *script1.sh* which is annoying. I just want to access only the exported variables in *script1* and donot want to run the commands in *script1* while calling that in *script2*.

Kindly help!

Thanks,
Karthik

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do (only get the variables from another script, without executing the commands) is not possible.

Here is a workaround:

Extract the variable declaration and initialisation to a third file, which is then sourced by both.

*common-vars:*

```
export a=10
export b=20
```

*script1.sh:*

```
. common-vars
echo "testing"
exit
```

*script2.sh:*

```
. common-vars
echo $a
```

Answer (score 2):

If your variable assignments are *only ever* in the *exact* form indicated above, that is

```
export a=10
```

then you could extract those assignments with `grep` and `eval` the results.  Your script2.sh would then be

```
eval `grep "^export " script1.sh`
echo $a
```

But doing this is very fragile, and can break in lots of ways.  Putting the variable assignments in a third script sourced by both as others have suggested is far safer.

This can break if you have variable settings inside conditionals, or if your exported variables depend on other non-exported variables that got missed, or if you set and export the variables separately; and if you happen to be using command substitution in your exports those would still get run with their possible side effects.

```
if [ $doexport = 1 ]; then
  export a=1
fi

a=2
export a

b=2
export a=$b

export a=`ls |wc -l`
```

These are all potentially problematic.

Comment: Both answers suggested by you and jlliagre really works but can you explain the limitation of using this approach in detail?

Answer (score 1):

Assigning a variable is a command. Unless you're prepared to write a bash parser in bash, what you want cannot be done.

Answer (score 1):

*script2.sh:*

```
eval "$(grep export script1.sh)"
echo $a
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams.

> Assigning a variable is a command

not much you can do about it.

A probable solution would be to seperate the variable definitions to a third script, that would be used as *configuration* script. So both *script1* and *script2* would `source` that one, to use the vars defined there.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with "Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams" this is a good answer to your question.

But I have another solution for you where you don't have export your variables. concept is based on : use you Login shell to run both the script instead of a new shell.

Lets say your script1.sh is :

```
a=10 

b=20
```

now run your script in your login shell :

Example:

```
.[space]script1
```

Now if you will access the variable a in your script it will be accessible to you without fail.

**Example**

Lets say your script2.sh is :

```
echo $a
```

run:

```
.[space]script2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the variable from one script to another by passing the variable as a parameter.
This of course means that Script B will be called by Script A. Script B will need to check that the parameter passed is not empty.